# Order of Execution of Subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT customerid, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM orders
WHERE customers.customerid = orders.customerid) as total_orders
FROM customers
```

Can anyone explain the working of this SQL code? The subquery should always return the same number of rows in this case according to me, because the total no. of rows where 
`customers.customerid = orders.customerid` is same. But its displaying each customer and the total_orders made by him/her. What is the order of execution that results in this?

Please find the database here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags. Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT c.customerid, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM orders o
        WHERE c.customerid = o.customerid
       ) as total_orders
FROM customers c;
```

(Note that I added table aliases and qualified all column names.)

This is a *scalar, correlated* subquery.  It is a scalar subquery because it returns a single value (rather than a table).

It is correlated because the subquery is linked to the outer query.  This is the part that confuses you.

Basically, the outer query says that the result set will have one row for each customer.

The subquery than says that for each customer, the result set will count the number of matching rows for the customer in any given row.

Although writing the query with a subquery is totally fine, this would often be written as:

```
SELECT c.customerid, COUNT(o.customerid) as total_orders
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.customerid = o.customerid
GROUP BY c.customerId
```

Comment: I had one doubt, say suppose the outer query gives 100 rows as output, will the inner query run 100 times? So total 101 times queries would be executed?

Comment: Short answer: no. `the order of execution` does not exist in SQL. (and if it exists, it should be irrelevant) You should see the inner query as an *expression* , yielding exactly one value for every row in the outer query.

Comment: @argo - To paraphrase Joop, exactly what gets executed depends on the DBMS.  SQL is a `declarative` language rather than an `imperative` language.  In SQL you write an expression that explains the logical problem you need to need to be solved, and then that is converted in to a "plan" to be executed on the available hardware *(which may be one thread, one core, one cpu, multiple cpus or even a cluster of machines)*.  You can think of the difference being that SQL is the algebraic formula you need solving, the plan is the algorithm used to solve it.  And that varies massively between RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically using the **Correlated** subquery which means your inner query is executed for each of the row of the outer query.

In your case, the inner query gets executed for all the customers because of the where clause `customers.customerid = orders.customerid`. So, the aggregate function `COUNT(*)` returns the total number of orders for every customer. Since your outer query selects customerId and total_orders that is why you get 2 columns.